# Retrieve the list of known SVG elements names at runtime

Tags: web, svg, dom

Is it possible to retrieve the list of known SVG elements found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element), or at least most of that, at runtime?

I need this list but I'd rather not ship ~1kb of code just to hard-code that in my app if I can reconstruct it at runtime somehow.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tested it? Dont underestimate gzip/brotli compression

Comment: The code that needs to be parsed has to be uncompressed anyway. I'm interested in making that smaller for this particular use case.

Comment: Your server does compression by default... I  hope

Comment: I basically have no server, just the client side, so no compression. Not that whether compression is enabled or not matters regarding how long it takes to parse code.